# Magento: Updating item custom options in shopping cart programmatically?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I want to update the custom options from an item in the cart. I have the items id, so I could load the item in my controller. Thats where I am stuck, I can remove the item from the cart and add a new one with the updated options, but thats not what I want.

I wantto update the existing item in the cart directly. Any ideas  how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you paste the code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact problem with configurable products.

For now, I know that Magento displays configurable products options on 'edit cart item' page, and the list of options is generated without pre-selection of configurable attribute. The attribute is set by the javascript, which takes data generated by

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
```

But it displays selected attribute only on 'edit cart item' page.
If I call it manually, it doesn't show current attribute selection.

Some checkout modules also display selected attribute in cart overwiew, as I know - so, it's possible to take that data from Magento (but I'm not sure if it was taken directly from the DB or in some more friendly way).

Answer (score 0):

config.xml part

```
<events>
    <checkout_cart_update_items_after>
        <observers>
            <update_items_specific_option>
                <class>mycompany_checkout/observer</class>
                <method>updateItemsSpecificOption</method>
            </update_items_specific_option>
        </observers>
    </checkout_cart_update_items_after>
</events>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/Observer.php part

```
<?php

class MyCompany_Checkout_Model_Observer
    extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function updateItemsSpecificOption($observer)
    {
        $event  = $observer->getEvent();
        $cart   = $event->getCart();
        $data   = $event->getInfo();

        foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
            $item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
            if (!$item) {
                continue;
            }

            $optionData = $this->_getSpecificOptionDataFromItem($item);
            if(!$optionData) {
                continue;
            }

            $params = clone $item->getBuyRequest();
            $options = $params->getOptions() ? $params->getOptions() : array();

            $updateItem = false;
            if($shouldIRemoveOption) {
                unset($options[$optionData['option_id']]);
                $updateItem = true;
            } elseif($shouldIAddOption) {
                $options[$optionData['option_id']] = array($optionData['value_id']);
                $updateItem = true;
            }

            if($updateItem) {
                $params->setOptions($options);
                $cart->updateItem($itemId, $params);
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getSpecificOptionDataFromItem($item)
    {
        foreach($item->getProduct()->getOptions() as $option) {
            if($this->_isMyNeededOption($option)) {
                foreach($option->getValues() as $valueId => $value) {
                    if($this->_isMyNeededValue($value)) {
                        return array(
                            'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                            'value_id'  => $valueId,
                            'price'     => $value->getPrice()
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I don't know where exactly you want to change custom options, so here you have an observer which does that during cart update action